# Configuration problems with django and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've got problems on getting django to work on apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi.
Django is installed and mod_wsgi too.
I can even see a 404 page when accessing the path and I can login to django admin.
But if I want to install the tagging module I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 49, in <module>
  version_tuple = __import__('tagging').VERSION
   File "/home/jim/django-tagging/tagging/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  from tagging.managers import ModelTaggedItemManager, TagDescriptor
   File "/home/jim/django-tagging/tagging/managers.py", line 5, in <module>
  from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 1, in <module>
  from django.db import models
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  if not settings.DATABASE_ENGINE:
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 269, in __getattr__
  self._setup()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 75, in __init__
  raise ImportError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
 ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named mysite.settings
```

My httpd.conf:

```
 Alias /media/ /home/jim/django/mysite/media/

 <Directory /home/jim/django/mysite/media>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

 Alias /admin/media/ "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"

 <Directory "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

 WSGIScriptAlias /dj /home/jim/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi

 <Directory /home/jim/django/mysite/apache>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

My django.wsgi:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('/home/jim/django')
sys.path.append('/home/jim/django/mysite')

os.chdir('/home/jim/django/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I try to get this to work since a few days and have read several blogs and answers here on so but nothing worked.

**Edit:**

Now I tried it with [this blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html) and my wsgi file now looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/jim/django/mysite')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/jim/django')

import settings

import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility()
command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')

command.validate()

import django.conf
import django.utils

django.utils.translation.activate(django.conf.settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

admin is still working, but I'm getting the same error when I try to install the tagging module.

Comment: Could you show us an absolute path to settings.py ?

Comment: @Ruslan Spivak
/home/jim/django/mysite/settings.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,

- Since your admin works, the setting with wsgi is good. Don't bother changing/editing it.

To ensure that it is not a Apache/mod-wsgi setting problem, you can run the development server from the production machine

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8080
```

Then point your browser to

```
http://yoursite.com:8080/
```

You must see exactly the same behaviour.

Then,

For debugging this problem:

- On the python shell on your server, try `import tagging`. Clearly, from your traceback, `import tagging` is where it is raising an error and thats why, settings cannot be imported.
- Then, Just delete the package containing tagging, and do a fresh install by the following command, which knows how to install packages, well.

.

```
sudo pip install django-tagging
```

Comment: import tagging does not work, even with the development server: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tagging

Comment: Jimbo: Thats exactly what I predicted. You can now read my answer carefully, to solve your problem!

Comment: never used pip before but it worked. don't know what caused the problem. I hope it was tagging specific so that I don't have the same problem with another package later on.. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Have you read Graham Dumpleton's [blog post on Django and WSGI](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html)? It does a pretty good job of describing some common configuration problems, and specifically touches on `mysite.settings` vs. `settings`.

UPDATE: Please read Graham Dumpleton's excellent comments below.

UPDATE 2: As both Graham and becomingGuru have pointed out, the problem is not with WSGI at all. It is instead a problem with your installation of `django-tagging`. Take becomingGuru's advice and use `pip` to install `django-tagging`.

Comment: Hope it fixes your specific problem.

Comment: Still got the same problem :/

Comment: Then you likely have a permissions problem. Apache runs as a special user and not you. Therefore the directories where Django site is, plus all parent directories down to that point, must be accessible to Apache user. If you have rwx------ on your home account then Apache will not be able to see inside of your account.

Comment: Alternatively if the site is working but only fails when adding this, then you possibly simply have introduced a syntax error in your settings file. Post the section of the settings file you modified.

Comment: Hmmm, no. Because the second WSGI import method imports settings in WSGI script file, if there was a syntax error in it, you should get different message. BTW, that blog post doesn't say to add '/home/jim/django' to sys.path, only the site directory itself. It shouldn't matter in this case though. Anyway, all doesn't matter, as just realised that original error message is not even from inside of mod_wsgi. It is from python being invoked on "setup.py" directly. Where are you doing that? Looks like you haven't set PYTHONPATH properly if executing on command line. The WSGI stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm running the setup.py of the django-tagging module from inside the directory located in /home/jim/django-tagging/setup.py. The permissions of /home/jim/django and /home/jim/django-tagging as well as /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django are set to rwxr-xr-x. The PYTHONPATH environment variable wasn't set. I set it to: /usr/lib/python2.5 but I keep having the problem

Comment: to understand it correctly as newbe django/linux user, just to get it right. The mysite.settings file does not exists on the filesystem. it's a 'link' to the settings.py in my mysite directory, right?

Comment: I also tried to set the PYTHONPATH to '/home/jim/django/mysite' but with no success

Comment: PYTHONPATH has to include parent directory of where your Django site is.