# How does one deploy a django application on OS X Server?

Tags: django, macos, apache2, mod-wsgi

How would one deploy a Django application on OS X Server 2.0 without using homebrew or a different flavor of python than the one shipped with OS X 10.8.1? I'm using the cocoa bindings in a Django application and had trouble getting it to work with homebrew on my desktop machine (running OS X 10.8.1); hence the request to deploy the application on the system installed version of Python.

I have the following OS X Server environment, with the following already installed:

- OS X 10.8.1
- OS X Server 2.0
- Python 2.7.2
- Apache 2.2.22

Django 1.4.1 was installed using the following command:

```
sudo easy_install django
```

My first attempt is to deploy an empty website, and once that succeeds, deploy a real application to be used in production. The project was created at `/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/mysite/` using the following command

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I ran the application using the following command. It simply confirmed that the application was up and running. It is the standard "It worked!" page when you first created a project.

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

I then created a file `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_mysite.conf` with the following content:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

I further created a file `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps/com.example.mysite.wsgi.plist` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-7"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>com.example.mysite.wsgi</string>
        <key>displayName</key>
        <string>Python "My Site" app</string>
        <key>launchKeys</key>
        <array/>
        <key>proxies</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>installationIndicatorFilePath</key>
        <string>/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py</string>
        <key>includeFiles</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_mysite.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>requiredModuleNames</key>
        <array>
                <string>wsgi_module</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file `com.example.mysite.wsgi.plist` was adapted from `com.apple.webapp.wsgi.plist` and `httpd_mysite.conf` adapted from `httpd_wsgi.conf`. Both these files are used to run the "standalone" python application successfully when configured through the server manager.

I then created a site with the server manager, confirmed my application was in the list of web applications. However, when I visit http://example.com/mysite I get a 500 error. The logs has the following entries (IP addresses changed to 1.2.3.4 for privacy reasons):

```
[Sat Sep 01 21:49:17 2012] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sat Sep 01 21:49:17 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.13 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 01 21:50:13 2012] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' failed
[Sat Sep 01 21:50:13 2012] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] Premature end of script headers: wsgi.py
```

It doesn't seem that the WSGI module is handling the request, but instead, the request may be processed using FCGI. However, the log indicates that `mod_wsgi/3.3` was loaded.

When I created a standard Python application that looks as follows:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

And update the files to point to `/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/helloworld.wsgi` rather than `/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py` then "Hello World" is displayed. I therefore assume that wsgi is correctly configured and able to execute applications and that something else is wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Apache configurations with distros map .py to either CGI or FASTCGI and this will conflict with mod_wsgi. This is why mod_wsgi recommends using a .wsgi extension. So, rename 'wsgi.py' to 'site.wsgi' and then use 'site.wsgi' in the WSGIScriptAlias.

BTW, can you confirm that there is a precompiled mod_wsgi.so shipped with Mountain Lion server.

Comment: It is installed at `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so`

Comment: You were correct, renaming `wsgi.py` to `mysite.wsgi` invoked `mod_wsgi`. I ran into other problems which was solved by adding the paths using `sys.path.append` in `mysite.wsgi` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587251/configuration-problems-with-django-and-mod-wsgi). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself struggling to migrate my macports django to Mountain Lion Server 10.8.2, and for some reason the answers here helped me remember the mod_wsgi.so differences.

I overwrote the /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so with my /opt/local/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so.

I was hoping to remove the MacPorts apache2 completely, but I think I better keep it around. I still prefer MacPorts Python at the moment, since it is easier to keep up to date with the numerically intensive packages.

Yes, also make sure you change that wsgi.py to wsgi.wsgi.

I copied httpd_wsgi.conf to httpd_mywsgi.conf; I added my django.wsgi to /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps.
In /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps, I copied the com.apple.webapp.wsgi.plist.

It looks like you chose the same plist pattern.

I am still working out my static content, however, thought the mod_wsgi.so discovery could help someone else migrating from MacPorts.

Comment: Your .so file will get overridden on an OS update if they update mod_wsgi. You should have put your version elsewhere and changed the LoadModule line for mod_wsgi in the Apache configuration.

Comment: Good point @GrahamDumpleton , and it is a red flag whenever you find yourself copying over load modules.

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

1. If you want to use the WSGIScriptAlias directive you need to have the mod_wsgi apache module. I don't have OS X server but as far as I can see the module does not exists in the /usr/libexec/apache2 folder on mountain lion standard. You gonna have to download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/). Don't know if the command line tools are included in the OS X server. I do need to install X code to get them on the standard version. There seems to be some [instruction on how to install it on macos x](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnMacOSX)
2. Have a look at [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew). This is a really great way to add extra software to the mac. In a twist you could install the latest python, nginx and uwsgi. Nginx and uwsgi is a great way to deploy django apps. I find it more flexible and efficient than mod_wsgi (this second point is highly subjective).

Good luck

Comment: The mod_wsgi package may not be in Mountain Lion standard, but a report I had before it was released said that it was in Mountain Lion server. Haven't had confirmation of that yet though since released.

Comment: The module exists at `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so`

Comment: As described in my question, I use the Cocoa bindings in my application and had some trouble to get it to work using Homebrew. I'd would therefore rather avoid it.